# How to edit the matching record set?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am using the below two codes one to download outlook mails and another to update it. I have no issues with the first code which downloads mails. However when I use the second code to find the task and make some additions to the corresponding  recordset sometimes wrong recordset is getting updated could you assist me?
The senttime and sentto is reflecting for the wrong task

First code:

```vb
Private Sub getml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application

Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim var As variant 
Set db = CurrentDb

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set inbox = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
Set inboxItems = inbox.Items
On error resume next
For Each Mailobject In inboxItems
   set var = MailObject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
IF Not (var Is Nothing) Then
       With rst 
           .FindFirst "task=" Chr(34) & var & Chr(34)
        If .NoMatch then
            .AddNew
            !task= var.value & ""
            .Update

            Mailobject.UnRead = False
        End If
    End With
End If
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set inbox = Nothing
Set inboxItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
End sub
```

Second code

```vb
Private Sub stml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application

Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim var As variant 
Set db = CurrentDb

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set inbox = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
Set inboxItems = inbox.Items
On error resume next
For Each Mailobject In inboxItems
   set var = MailObject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
IF Not (var Is Nothing) Then
       With rst 
           .FindFirst "task=" Chr(34) & var & Chr(34)
        If not .NoMatch then
            .edit
            !senttime= MailObject.Receivedtime
            !sentto = mailobject.to
            .Update

            Mailobject.UnRead = False
        End If
    End With
End If
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set inbox = Nothing
Set inboxItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a second check to verify that the record is the one you want.

```vb
If Not (var Is Nothing) Then
       With rst 
           .FindFirst "task=" Chr(34) & var & Chr(34)
        If Not .NoMatch  Then
            If !task = CStr(Nz(var))
                .edit
                !senttime= MailObject.Receivedtime
                !sentto = mailobject.to
                .Update

                Mailobject.UnRead = False
            End If
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Note that it might be useful to print out or log records that fail the `!task = CStr(Nz(var))` check. My best guess is that `var` is `Null` for these values.